# Locked Excel Cells Becoming Unlocked When Re Opened

Tags: excel, blueprism

I have a Blueprism process which is locking a column and protecting the worksheet. The cells are then locked. When the file is saved, closed and re opened the cells are no longer locked.

```
GetInstance(handle).Activecell.Locked = True
GetInstance(handle).ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was I was using a CSV. Doesn't seem to work there but does in a standard Excel Workbook.

Comment: A CSV is basically just a plain text file that *Excel* decides display in a fancy manner.  It holds none of the extra stuff like cell formatting, macros, etc.  However, you *could* change the metadata to flag the **file** as "Read Only"

Comment: What was throwing me was it would work before closing out but then on re opening it was gone. Also annoyingly I thought  I had tested in a non csv workbook but obviously not!

Answer (score 0):

Most of these cases are related to excel Settings, not exactly the Blueprism. I would suggest trying with Options Menu in Excel workbook and Remove Recovery flags as well.

Control+A and format sheet to Text Type and Save Manually First(One Time activity). Sometimes Formatting can be the root cause.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).